# What is the SURE way to ensure Microsoft Distribution Tool to only format C Drive?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, wds, mdt-2012, waik

Right now I'm using "Specific disk and partition" but is it the best way to do this? I have almost 100 pc to format which have other drives in them with data already. I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2 and the PC will be formatted to Win7 Professional.